# Angular Flex Layout - Simple Layout ( Header, Container, Footer)

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'd like to have a simple Layout with Header, Container and Footer.

My HTML-Code look like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column">
  <header style="background-color: lightblue; height: 20px">
    Header
  </header>
  <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100">
    <div style="background-color: red" fxFlex="1 1 auto"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue" fxFlex="5 1 auto"></div>
    <div style="background-color: green" fxFlex="2 2 auto"></div>
    <div style="background-color: maroon; height: 200px" fxFlex="1 1 auto"></div>
  </div>
  <footer style="height: 40px; background-color: yellow">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

But i like to stretch the Container verticaly. The footer should be on the bottom of the Screen. Can you help me?

Comment: Use `style="height: 100%;"` in outermost div

Comment: I don't use angular much, but here's the plain vanilla solution: https://jsfiddle.net/379nwh0a/5/